# textmate railscast theme and font?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate

where can I get the textmate rails theme and font used on Railscast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BAH. Found both here http://mattonrails.tumblr.com/post/210920872/inconsolata-font

font is Inconsolata monospace
Theme is also linked above

Answer (score 5):

5 seconds on google reveal that there is a link to the complete theme on the railscasts.com site itself (http://railscasts.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

This is the link to Ryans Railscasts Theme:
_http://media.railscasts.com/resources/textmate_theme.zip

This is the link to Bitstream Vera Sans Mono Font he uses:
_http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/ttf-bitstream-vera/1.10/ttf-bitstream-vera-1.10.zip

Font-wise I would prefer DejaVu Sans Mono (it is based on Bitstream but has more characters):
_http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Download

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the theme (couldn't find a theme with the exact same colors), but it looks like it's the Menlo font with the size of about 12-14 pt. I'm using the built-in Pastels on Dark theme and it looks quite similar. You could change some of the colors to match your taste.

Answer (score 0):

The themes where pushed to [github](https://github.com/ryanb/textmate-themes) by Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Monaco seems like an awesome font to use for programming. A monospace font is a must while coding since it can maintain the indentations properly.